# Does the c# keyword var slow compilation?

Tags: c#, type-inference

C# has the `var` keyword which forces the compiler to infer variable types.
The c# compiler also has to check if type of variable is compatible with assigned value.

I heard that `var` can slow compilation and that I shouldn't use it much but I like being lazy and letting compiler do work for me especially that you have to assign value to variable declared with `var`  during declaration.

So does it affect dramatically compilation time while used a lot?

Comment: Have you measured compilation time with and without frequent use of `var`?

Comment: _"But also c# compiler has to check if type of variable is compatible with assigned value."_  Not completely. The type of the variable is the type of the assigned value.

Comment: Do you have any projects that take more than a few seconds to build?  If not, it's highly unlikely that you will ever notice or care about the time it takes the compiler to infer variable types.

Comment: _"I heard that var can slow compilation and that I shouldn't use it much but I like being lazy and letting compiler do work"_  It's probably said by someone who is not willing to evolve and stick to the old times' sake 3rd generation languages

Comment: There are other reasons against always using `var` like that it's not always clear what type is assigned.

Comment: I heard it from my teacher and I don't agree with it so I thought I'd ask, yeas I mean while used a lot

Comment: van Langen I also I think so but I won't change teacher mind :P

Comment: @MaciejKozieja If you actually expect to convince someone then rather than asking strangers on the internet if it will take longer you should just write a test, measure the performance difference, and have conclusive evidence one way or the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have **HUGE** projects that take (tens of) *minutes* to build, any performance differences that may be caused by `var` will be unnoticeable.

Keep in mind that with or without `var` the compiler *already* has to do a lot of type-compatibility checking, so it already has the information to "infer" the type.  Avoiding `var` doesn't eliminate this type checking.

> I heard that `var` can slow compilation and that I shouldn't use it much ...

This sounds like an excuse proffered by someone who is opposed to using `var`.

---

This leads to the question of when to use `var`, and opinions and preferences differ on *that* topic; perhaps legitimately, there is (arguably) potential for over-use.  My **personal** *preference* is to use `var` only in three fairly clear situations:

- when you must, i.e., anonymous types: `var foo = new { Foo = 314 };`
- when the variable type is (very) complex, often the result of a LINQ query
- when the actual type is "completely obvious":

  - `var foo = (Foo) obj;` or `var foo = obj as Foo;`
  - `var foo = new Foo();`
  - `var foo = Foo.Create();`

Comment: I love var but my teacher says that using bar is not good in c# and he will give me lover degrees if I'm using it and during this debate he said this argument so I had to ask

Comment: or dynamic types.

Comment: @nathangonzalez `dynamic`?

Comment: @Rawling, was in reply to @Dan, or maybe in addition to.  I can't imagine someone who is against `var` for compilation time to be ok with `dynamic`

Comment: @Rawling dynamic types using `var` ?